# How to upload photo into Filemaker database using script

Tags: filemaker

The requirement is to upload a photo in database through script in FileMaker. I tried with Insert Picture in script but it is not working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to upload the photo. We need to create fields with type container and in script we have to user "Go to field" where point to the created fileds and then Insert Picture[] with location where the picture exist. It will upload the photo into the field.